# Updating app automatically when online database updated. Possible?

Tags: android, database-connection

I have an online database of music files. I want that if i update the database(add or delete files), the application automatically updates the new files into the app. Is that possible??

Answer (score 0):

You could poll a web service that has access to the database to check for updates, but this is generally discouraged if you need to poll frequently.

Or, you could use Google Cloud Messaging to send push notifications to the client when the database updates http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html.